# Laravel: Writing to /.../.config/psysh is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have installed a Laravel app locally using the [Laravel Installer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation#installing-laravel). Now I want to upload the app to my production server which is a managed virtual server, but it fulfills all the needed [requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation#server-requirements).

I have uploaded the app and changed in the `.env` file the `APP_URL` and the `DB_*` settings accordingly. When I login to my server via ssh, go inside the app folder and try to use tinker

```
php artisan tinker
```

I get the following error message:

[image]

The error message makes sense, because the `wp10***` folder does not contain a `.config` folder. However, I do not have permission to create folders at the same level as the `www` folder. Is it possible to put the folder inside the Laracast project folder? In my example this would be `/is/htdocs/wp_10**/www/laracast/p1/.config/psysh`. If so, how do I tell Laravel the new location?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tinker is trying to create the `.config` folder, and it's not per-app configuration, it's stored against the user.

I don't think you can change the directory path, but creating the directory and setting permissions on it will allow you to use tinker.

`mkdir -p ~/.config/psysh
chmod -R 755 ~/.config`

It is worth double checking the user permissions before you try this, as you should always be able to write directly to your users home directory.

Comment: in my case 755 is making problem, thats why i've given 777 permission.

Comment: Bad idea to run chmod -R 755 ~/.config on whole config folder recursively, there are logs of other configs and files that don't need execution permission

Comment: @sh6210 ya me too had to use 777

Comment: You can set the env variable in your .env file `PSYSH_CONFIG=/path/to/.config/psysh/config.php`

Answer (score 22):

If you can't give access to use the default directory,

**You can change the directory path in `.env` file:**

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/home/some/directory
```

Thanks to [bernhardh](https://github.com/beyondcode/nova-tinker-tool/issues/5#issuecomment-419915192)

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything for me

Comment: @tofandel maybe it's not available in your Laravel version

Comment: This comes in super handy when running artisan in docker under a different user

Comment: try `php artisan config:clear` after you add the config. It is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use :

`sudo chmod -R 755 ~/.config`

then make directory:

`mkdir -p ~/.config/psysh`

and :

`php artisan tinker`.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that `.config` and `psysh` belong to your user, try changing the owner with `chown` and set the permissions to `700`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a Laravel 9 app running in a non-root Docker container.

I fixed it by creating the matching user inside of the container so that it gets a home directory. Then, Psysh was able to write its config in the user's home.

With that setup, no need to change any `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` or `PSYSH_CONFIG` vars.

Moreover, using those `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` or `PSYSH_CONFIG` env vars is irrelevant if you use Laravel config caching.

Comment: This is exactly the solution I'm looking for. Could you elaborate on it ? You created a user in your docker-compose file ? I have a user: 1000:1000 in both my containers, yet I still get that issue.

Comment: If you run your container as user 1000 with `user: "1000:1000"` in your Compose file, you need to have a real user with ID `1000` in your container. That means your Docker image needs to have this user created before runtime. And that shall be done in your image `Dockerfile` with `RUN adduser johndoe --uid 1000`. Then pull your image, rebuild your container and you're done.

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked for me. Crazy how a sub-comment is better than the actual solutions posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.config
```

If Directory is not exists

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/psysh
```

Then check again

```
php artisan tinker
```

Answer (score 0):

if working with Laragon on windows you can try go to c drive then click on the user folder you are using then right click and then properties go to security and then click edit(all/everyone). Then check all the boxes so you are permitted to write to the file.[how it looks here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vepCR.png)

Answer (score -2):

**Fixed!** For Windows, run your terminal or app as an administrator.