# Cannot write to `psysh ` directory when using docker-compose with Laravel tinker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have a containerized Laravel app. All my containers are running. When I run the command `docker-compose exec app php artisan tinker`, I get the error

```
   ErrorException 

  Writing to directory /home/darula/.config/psysh is not allowed.
```

Other artisan commands like `docker compose exec app php artisan migrate` work just fine.

I tried to change the ownership of the directory to the current owner. Also tried to change the permissions of the .config directory to `755`. When I run `php artisan tinker` without the `docker-compose`, the command runs just file. Also when I run the `php artisan tinker` in a non containerized app, it works just fine.

Anything I need to do in order to run tinker on a containerized app?

Answer (score 1):

I encontered the same error, after creating a customized docker for my project.

Don't know if it is your case, but in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467774/laravel-writing-to-config-psysh-is-not-allowed#comment130111227_73635736), it says that docker needs a valid user to run.

To check just attach the docker shell running the laravel app and see if it the 'user' appears as having no name.

If it doesn't have a "name" you just need to modify your Dockerfile script addding a user.

```
# Variables to configure user and permissions
ARG WWWUSER=www
ARG WWWGROUP=www
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g ${GID} ${WWWGROUP}
RUN useradd -u ${UID} -ms /bin/bash -g ${WWWGROUP} ${WWWUSER}

USER ${WWWUSER}
```

You can pass the argumments as a variable in your `docker-compose.yml` usually UID and GID are 1000, to confirm you can run:

```
id -u # To check your user ID
```

and

```
id -g # To check your group
```

The WWWUSER and WWWGROUP is just a user to run your system as internally, like sail.

Re-build your container and start it up. In my case it fixed.