How can i make my artisan tinker writeable?
I'm doing a Laravel project, and i want to do crud database on the php command line
i do php artisan tinker on mu vscode laravel project, and then I got an error message that sounds
 ErrorException 

  Writing to directory /.config/psysh is not allowed.

  at vendor/psy/psysh/src/ConfigPaths.php:327
    323▕             @\mkdir($dir, 0700, true);
    324▕         }
    325▕ 
    326▕         if (!\is_dir($dir) || !\is_writable($dir)) {
  ➜ 327▕             \trigger_error(\sprintf('Writing to directory %s is not allowed.', $dir), \E_USER_NOTICE);
    328▕ 
    329▕             return false;
    330▕         }
    331▕ 

how can i fixed this problem?
I'm expecting I can edit/change the database using commandline php artisan tinker

On what OS are you running your Laravel?

Check the link, this might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467774/laravel-writing-to-config-psysh-is-not-allowed

@Sitethief I'm running it on MacOS Ventura

Like @Subha said, the ~/.config/psysh folder might not be present or accessible for the user running the command

when writing on the file system of your project, it could be better to first open a shell as the webserver user. This way files created will have the same permissions as the webserver.
